# Cannot upload PGP key to launchpad

Tags: package-management, gnupg, launchpad

I cannot understand why my PGP key was refused by Launchpad:

[image: Error message from Launchpad]

I have generated a key (RSA,4096 with no expiration) and have properly uploaded using

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys <key_id>
```

**What would be the origin of the refusal of Launchpad to accept my key?**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the size of the key has to be minimal (1024)